# OpenCV floodfill error

Tags: android, opencv, flood-fill

I have an application using OpenCV and im trying to implement `floodfill` after using `canny edge` and use `findcontours` and `boundingrect` to get colored letters and *segment* each words or line of words.

I already implemented it but I dont see the result of `floodfill`, the result image is only canny edge. I tried to remove canny and use `floodfill` but i get a lighter color (white-ish) of the image.

here is my code (after canny edge - `floodfill` part):

```
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, morByte, Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, kernel);
    Imgproc.findContours(morByte, contour2, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    Imgproc.floodFill(morByte, flooded, flood, new Scalar(255,255,255), new Rect(), lowerDiff, upperDiff, 4);
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696914/using-opencv-flood-fill) (current implemented `floodfill` line). I also tried to change `flooded` variable to `mask` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275407/opencv-floodfill-doesnt-change-mask-image) and it's an error/crashes.

I also tried to change my code based from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705721/opencv-floodfill-with-mask) but I get this error:

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/floodfill.cpp:556: error: (-215) mask.rows == size.height+2 && mask.cols == size.width+2 in function int cv::floodFill(cv::InputOutputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::Point, cv::Scalar, cv::Rect*, cv::Scalar, cv::Scalar, int)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you could reduce your problem into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In it's current form, this is a lot of code for people to work through, which makes it less likely that you will get an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question already. It is still about the floodfill function of OpenCV.